# Set up IIS to reverse proxy an internal server

Tags: iis, flask

I have a Linux server serving a Flask application with Gunicorn.  I have a separate Windows server with IIS.  Only the IIS server is accessible publicly.  How can I set up IIS as a reverse proxy to my internal server?

PS: came from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022105/set-up-iis-to-reverse-proxy-an-internal-server

Comment: What is your operating system on IIS server?

Comment: It's Windows 10 for IIS and RH7 for the flask

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by installing the URL Rewrite and Application Request Routing modules for IIS. These can easily be installed with the [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) from Microsoft.

Once installed, you can use the URL Rewrite GUI to create reverse proxy rules. You can find a simple example at [Scott Forsyth's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) on the offical asp.net website .

Comment: Will this allow us to use a self-signed certificate on the linux/flask server without getting that annoying security warning? (the Windows/IIS server has a properly signed cert)